# Sql retrieve fields without a relation in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have 2 tables: Customers and Orders. A customer has many orders and an order belongs to a customer. The order can be approved (marked by a field approved_at).
I want to retrieve all the customers without any approved order. This includes customers without any order and customers with orders that aren't approved (approved_at = null).
Can I do this in a single query without subqueries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ..., COUNT(Orders.id) AS cnt
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders ON (Customers.id = Orders.Customer_id) AND (Orders.approved_at is null)
HAVING cnt = 0
```

Comment: I knew that was something related to the "HAVING".
Although, it's missing the group by. The final query is:
`SELECT Customers.*, COUNT(Orders.id) cnt`
`FROM Customers `
`LEFT JOIN Orders ON (Customers.id = Orders.Customer_id) AND (Orders.approved_at is null)`
`GROUP BY Customers.id`
`HAVING cnt = 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Orders o ON c.ID = o.CustomerID
WHERE o.ID IS NULL OR c.Approved_at IS NULL
```